# Python 3, Multiplication Table with 2D List using While Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't need an answer, just a jumping off point if possible.

I've made a multiplication table that prints 1-10, but my professor would like to see the table stored in a 2D list. I have my current code (working code, which is posted here), and new code I've made specifically for the "2D List" version, but I'm getting nowhere with either.

**EDIT:** I should probably clarify that the code is doing what I want it to do, which is outputting a multiplication table, but I am having trouble converting it into a 2D list.

```
#Initial list and global variables
MT = ["X", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10]
mult = 1
jump = 0
repeat = 1
list = 1

while repeat < 12:
    index = 1
    mult = 1
    jump += 1
    MT.append(MT[list])
    while (index < 11):
        MT.append(mult * jump)
        mult += 1
        index += 1
    else:
        repeat += 1
        list += 1
else:
    print("Multiplication Table:")
    index = 0
    while (index < 121):
        if (((index + 1) % 11) != 0):
            print(MT[index], end = "\t")
        else:
            print(MT[index], end = "\n")
        index += 1
```

Comment: What does "not getting anywhere" mean?

Comment: "Not getting anywhere" as in, none of the work I've done to adjust the code is outputting anything close to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to start off with a 2D list:

```
MT = [["X", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10]]
```

rather than what you have.

Start a new empty list right before the inner while loop. You can initialize it with the first value `new_row = [repeat]`. Inside that loop append to the `new_row` rather than MT

After that while loop is done, you can append the `new_row` to `MT`

`MT.append(new_row)`

---

That should get you started with the 2d list. However, while I have you here...

If you need to repeat and keep track of how many times you've repeated, then use a for loop rather than a while loop.

For example, if you want a loop that goes from 2 to 12 you'd use:

```
for repeat in range(2, 13):
    print(repeat)
```

Also, never overwrite built-in keywords as that can lead to unexpected behavior. So name `list` something else but I don't think that variable is really needed since it is similar to `repeat`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm adding these changes, and it's making a bit more sense. I also appreciate the advice. Made sure to change that variable.